# Problem with showing the integrability of $\int_{B}(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}d\lambda^2(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

> Define $B:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^{2}: x^2+y^2\leq1\}$, determine whether
>
> $$
> \int_{B}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}d\lambda^2(x,y)
> \quad \text{and} \quad
> \int_{\mathbb R^2-B}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}d\lambda^2(x,y)
> $$ are integrable.

**My ideas:**

Set $C:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R_{+}^{2}: x^2+y^2\leq1\}$ to get
$$
\begin{split}
I &= \int_{B}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}d\lambda^2(x,y) \\
  &= 2\int_{C}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} d\lambda^2(x,y)
     \quad \text{and using polar coordinates} \\
  &= 2\int_0^1 \int_0^\pi \frac{rd\phi dr}{r^3} \\
  &= 2\pi \left[\left.-\frac{1}{r}\right|_{0}^{1}\right]
   =\infty
\end{split}
$$

I do not know what to say on the case 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2-B}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}d\lambda^2(x,y).$$
It is clear that it is not integrable but how do I show this?

**Questions**:

1. In the above case finding 
   $$
   \int_B \left|\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right|d\lambda^2(x,y)
   $$ was easy due to the symmetry of on $B$, but how can I solve a problem like when there is no symmetry involved? Do I simply divide the functions in positive and negative parts?
2. Our professors are very pedantic on the use of correct reasoning. I need to reason why I can write $$\int_{B}|\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}|d\lambda^2(x,y),$$ in other words I need to reason why $$\left|\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right|$$ is measurable but surely I cannot show this as ($f$ measurable $\Rightarrow |f|$ measurable ) is not true in general is it?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is measurable then $|f|$ is measurable (since $|\cdot|$ is continuous). // Your computation of the integral on $C$ is wrong since, first, the change of variables reads $dxdy=rdrd\phi$ and not $drd\phi$. Even after that, $\frac14r^4$ is not a primitive of $\frac1{r^3}$.

Comment: @Did I've corrected it. In the above case $\int_B \left|\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right|d\lambda^2(x,y)=\infty$, but what can I say about $\int_{\mathbb R^2-B} \left|\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\right|d\lambda^2(x,y)$?

Comment: By the same reasoning, you are led to the integral of $1/r^2$ on $(1,\infty)$, which converges, hence the integral on $\mathbb R^2\setminus B$ converges.